# Eclipse-Java: where to put file for Read purpose

Tags: java

I'm programming Java in Eclipse IDE. Here is code I want to read file:

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

I put `file.txt` in two place:

1)  same folder of this SOURCE file.

2) in `bin\...\` (same folder of this CLASS file)

But I allways receive NO FILE FOUND.

Please help me.

thanks :)

Comment: You can set the directory from which the app will be executed from--if you're just opening a file, put it at the root of the project, and make sure you're executing it from there.

Comment: try in the root of the project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file ships with your application, it would be better accessed as a *resource* than as a file. Simply copy it to somewhere in your build path and use [`Class.getResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) or [`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). That way you'll *also* be able to access it if you bundle your app as a jar file.

Currently, you're looking for the file relative to the process's current working directory, which could be entirely unrelated to where the class files are.

Comment: Thanks :) Not what I need. Because I just test my app. But your way help me so much for other resources.

Answer (score 4):

if you put the file under sources and inside the package "test" for example, the path is:

./src/test/file.txt

you can use

File file = new File("./src/test/file.txt");

System.out.println(file.exists());

The path ./bin/test/file.txt will work in the second case and is more suitable for a normal java project